# Remove add post for user role

Tags: user-roles

I add new role with WP Members, I also use Publishpress and user role editor
For my new role, I want to disable the capability to create posts (built-in not custom post), not only with CSS but the entire capability. My custom role can only edit post
I know it's possible, I already see that but I can't find how to do this.

I tried to remove_cap('create_post') but it doesn't work

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I have posted the answer to _this_ question, but you've fallen into the trap of asking how to implement your solution, not how to solve your problem. If you had asked how to remove the add new UI or how to prevent users from creating posts at the database level, then there are solutions for that, ***but they do not involve capabilities***. I recommend you ask a new question focused on your original problem

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible using the capabilities system**, the granularity you want does not exist in WP core:

> #### edit_posts
>
> - Since 2.0
> - Allows access to Administration Screens options:
>
>   - Posts
>   - ***Posts > Add New***
>   - Comments
>   - Comments > Awaiting Moderation

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#edit_posts

`edit_posts` covers both viewing, adding, and editing posts, as well as commenting. There is a capability that controls wether you can edit other peoples posts however, but that isn't what you asked for.

Internally, the lowest abstraction before we get to raw SQL is `wp_insert_post`, which handles both post creation, and post updating. The only difference between creating a post and editing a post is wether a post ID is in the array passed to `wp_insert_post` ( `wp_update_post` is just a wrapper around `wp_insert_post` )